# How can I use an environment variable as a name for a docker container?

Tags: docker, environment-variables, docker-container

I want to name a docker container using and environment variable, something t=like:

`NAME=TEST docker run --name ${NAME}`

I tried several approaches for interpreting the environment variable, but I ran out of ideas.

My trials so far:

- $NAME
- ${NAME}
- `${NAME}`
- `NAME`

Any idea how that is possible?

Comment: `NAME=busybox && docker run -it --name ${NAME} busybox` ?

Comment: or `sh -c "NAME=test docker run -it --name ${NAME} busybox"`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [Francois Maturel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4757672/fran%C3%A7ois-maturel) said, the following is working:

```
NAME=TEST && docker run --name ${NAME} -it -d ubuntu bash
```

And this:

```
export NAME=TEST
docker run --name ${NAME} -it -d ubuntu bash
```

And:

```
NAME=TEST sh -c 'docker run --name ${NAME} -it -d ubuntu bash'
```